# Error de compilación al usar make o make install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

A la hora de lanzar el comando `make` o `make install` me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error (es la primera vez que posteo y no se como hacerlo de forma correcta, lo siento), no tengo demasiado conocimiento en la materia y necesito una ayuda al respecto. Realicé, antes de este, el comando `./config` y posteriormente he landazo `make update` para terminar con este comando y que me aparezca el error que os muestro abajo:

```
alvaro@alvaro-VirtualBox:~/Descargas/pennmush_1.8.2p8.orig/pennmush-1.8.2p8$ make install
echo "Localizing for your locale..."
Localizing for your locale...
(cd po; make localized)
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/alvaro/Descargas/pennmush_1.8.2p8.orig/pennmush-1.8.2p8/po'
make[1]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'es_ES.UTF-8.po', necesario para 'localized'.  Alto.
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/alvaro/Descargas/pennmush_1.8.2p8.orig/pennmush-1.8.2p8/po'
make: [Makefile:84: localized] Error 2 (no tiene efecto)
Making all in src.
(cd src; make all "CC=cc" "CCFLAGS=-g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include  " \
"LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib" "CLIBS=-lssl -lcrypto " "MAKE=make" \
"MAKEFLAGS=")
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/alvaro/Descargas/pennmush_1.8.2p8.orig/pennmush-1.8.2p8/src'
rm -f ../hdrs/buildinf.h
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o access.o access.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o atr_tab.o atr_tab.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o attrib.o attrib.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o boolexp.o boolexp.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o bsd.o bsd.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o bufferq.o bufferq.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o chunk.o chunk.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o cmdlocal.o cmdlocal.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o cmds.o cmds.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o command.o command.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o compress.o compress.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o cque.o cque.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o create.o create.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o db.o db.c
db.c: In function ‘db_paranoid_write_object’:
db.c:765:31: warning: ‘sprintf’ may write a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Wformat-overflow=]
  765 |           sprintf(tbuf1, "%s%d", name, count);
      |                               ^
db.c:765:11: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 2 and 8203 bytes into a destination of size 8192
  765 |           sprintf(tbuf1, "%s%d", name, count);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o destroy.o destroy.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o extchat.o extchat.c
extchat.c: In function ‘channel_description’:
extchat.c:2884:24: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 30 bytes into a region of size between 0 and 8191 [-Wformat-overflow=]
  2884 |       sprintf(buf, "%s %s", buf, ChanName(c->chan));
      |                        ^~
extchat.c:2884:7: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 2 and 8223 bytes into a destination of size 8192
  2884 |       sprintf(buf, "%s %s", buf, ChanName(c->chan));
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o extmail.o extmail.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o filecopy.o filecopy.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o flaglocal.o flaglocal.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o flags.o flags.c
cc -g -I.. -I../hdrs -I/usr/local/include       -c -o funcrypt.o funcrypt.c
funcrypt.c: In function ‘safe_sha0’:
funcrypt.c:118:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA’; did you mean ‘SHA1’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  118 |   SHA((unsigned char *) text, len, hash);
      |   ^~~
      |   SHA1
funcrypt.c: In function ‘fun_digest’:
funcrypt.c:162:14: error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known
  162 |   EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
      |              ^~~
make[1]: *** [<integrado>: funcrypt.o] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/alvaro/Descargas/pennmush_1.8.2p8.orig/pennmush-1.8.2p8/src'
make: *** [Makefile:33: all] Error 2
```

Comment: En relidad el error parece ser este: `funcrypt.c:162:14: error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known`. Sería bueno que proporcionaras más información sobre lo que estás tratando de compilar.

Comment: pennmush, es un MUD server... nos e que mas información darte